# Admob / Adsense Address verification PIN is not receive in DUBAI UAE?

Tags: adsense, admob

I've resubmitted Admob address verification **PIN 3** times but still not received.

***I've passed my threshold period too.***

**1'st Attempt** -  Add my residence address where I got almost all courier.

**2'nd Attempt** - Add my office address.

On detailed research, after 2 months I've found some forum post with same DUBAI UAE  address verification PIN not receiving due to POST OFFICE CODE **(P.O.BOX)** required in DUBAI.

On **my 3'rd Attempt** - I've tried my Office Address with P.O.BOX number. BUT Still PIN not arrived.

I'm very much disappointed on Google Services and lack of information on UAE postal service.

My whole payment is still uncleared (i.e. **AED** 30K+).

If someone from UAE or experienced with this type of issue - Please let me know.

**Thank you**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question; it is a customer service question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hie I had the same problem but after requesting the PIN for the 3rd time i waited 30 days. Then i attached my Emirates ID and Etisalat Telephone Bill showing my name and address. Within minutes i was verified and now will be receiving my payments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've Employment Card and DMCC Service license. Can both of valid ?
and one more thing - have you uploaded your  document in adMob panel directly OR you have any links for that? 

Thank you

Comment: Hie im not sure coz me i used Emirates ID and Etisalat Bill thats all. The upload link i found it in AdSense. You cant find it in AdMob. Login to AdSense and you will see the upload link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. I'm not sure but adMob also provide Document upload link where 3 PIN attempt completed. Will sure check it once my last attempt month will over. Last time i've requested my 3'rd PIN request at 11th-Sept. So I must wait from 11th-Oct. After that I hope it will active.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: I'm verified and got my payment in next day. Thank you sir

Comment: I have uploaded my emirates id, passport copy with visa, and bank statement. I have uploaded the documents last week but still, it is not yet verified. May I know how long does it take to verify it? It should have been verified in 2 working days.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I've added my Dubai ID proof with my company's service license and I've verified and got payment